# Can't cast class to its subclass?

Tags: java, casting

```
class Mid1Prob1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Testing...");
        int x = 3;
        System.out.println(3);
        System.out.println((int) x); // legal to cast primitive value to the same type as itself
        System.out.println((long) x); // legal to cast primitive value to a super type
        System.out.println((short) x); // legal to cast a primitive value to a sub type, but may lose information

        Actual act = new Actual();
        System.out.println(((Actual) act) .x); // legal to cast a reference value to the same class as itself
        System.out.println(((Super) act) .x); // legal to cast a reference value to a superclass of itself, as long as the superclass is actually a superclass of the current class
        System.out.println(((Sub) act) .x); // run-time error, cannot cast a reference value to its subclass
    }
}

class Super {
    public int x = 999;
}

class Actual extends Super {
    public int x = 666; // variables can be public in package-private class
}

class Sub extends Actual {
    public int x = 333;
}
```

Please examine the last line of the main() method, and compare it with the last line of the paragraph above it. Why can't I cast a reference value to its subclass, when I can cast a int to a short?

Comment: Just a heads up, `short` is by no means a subclass of `int`. The casting is just a rearrangement of the bit values equal to `int & 0xFFFF`.

Comment: `short` isn't a subtype of `int`. There's no inheritance hierarchy between primitives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
(Sub) act
```

You're telling the compiler (by the explicit cast) to trust you that you're not making errors, so it's ignoring the errors and doesn't detect it in *compilation* time. But when the program runs, you'll get an exception since `act` is `Actual` and not a `Sub`.

Answer (score 4):

There are many types of conversions. In this case, we are talking about [narrowing primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) (`int` to `short`) and [narrowing reference conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6) (parent type to child type).

> Why can't I cast a reference value to its subclass, but I can cast a
>   int to a short?

Because your `Actual` object is not of type `Sub`, so it can't be used as a `Sub` object.

You can always cast from `int` to `short`, but may lose information about the value.
The conversion is done as described in the Java Language Specification

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T
>   simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number
>   of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of
>   information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause
>   the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input
>   value.

Answer (score 2):

A `short` is not a subclass of an `int`. They're both completely independent ways of storing integar values; one is 2 bytes long and one is 4 bytes long (typically). That's why you're able to cast them to each other-- casting an `int` to a `short` will just ignore the upper 2 bytes of the `int`. However, with the other case, you can think of subclasses of having an "is" relationship. `Actual` *is* a `Super`. and `Sub` is an `Actual`. But an `Actual` ISN'T a `Sub` and this is why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't casting an int to a short, you're converting them, with possible loss of precision.  With object types, its a different story.

One of many reasons you can no do this in general is that "Sub" may rely on fields that just aren't there in "Actual".

Comment: Actually, they aren't.  They have the same name, but `Sub.x` is different than `Actual.x`. `Sub.x` hides `Actualy.x`.  In `Actual`, if you were to have a `printx()` method, it will print `Actual.x`, not `Sub.x`, even if the instance was a `Sub`.  In either case, my statement was general. You can't in general cast to a type that is lower on the hierarchy than the actual type. For this and other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what u are doing is you are trying to Cast integer into an Object. and which is not possible by this. you need to Cast that into the Object of the Super class.